# libGoogleAnalyticsv2.jar not included in signed APK anymore?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, analytics, apk

After switching from Eclipse Classic to the Eclipse ADT Bundle I made a few minor changes to an existing app today. I tested it on my physical device, everything worked as it should, so I exported it as a signed APK to upload to Google Play. When uploading, I noticed that the APK was only about 300kB, compared to the 700kB of the previous version. I had a look inside the APK-file and noticed that in the old version I have libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar and a folder called javadocs (which seems to come from the Google Analytics install). These are not present in the new build, hence the smaller file size.

Don't I need the .jar file to be in the APK for things to work? Or was it just added to my old APK by mistake, taking up 400kB for no reason at all?

The new build appears to be working fine, but I feel a bit hesitant to upload it to Google Play until I know what's going on...